# how to set and destroy cookie in same page without affecting the searching data?

Tags: php, cookies, pagination, session-cookies, setcookie

I am trying to search data and display data in same page with help of cookies.it is work fine but when i try to destroy cookies,the result data is loss and no searching happen.i also use `pagination`. when i click on another page no. in pagination,same the result data is lost.this is only happen when i destroy the cookies. and if i not destroy the cookies the data is continue display even i press enter in url.
                                                                                        `php code`:

```
   $depart_type=''; 
   if(isset($_COOKIE['depart_type']))
      {
        $depart_type = $_COOKIE['depart_type'];
      }   
    if($_POST['department_type']!='')
      {
        $depart_type = $_POST['department_type'];
        setcookie("depart_type",$depart_type,time()+3600,"/"); 
     }       
     $whr ="1";
    if($depart_type!="")
    {
        $whr .= "  AND `department_type` = '$depart_type'";
     } 
       $QryStaff = mysql_query("select * from `tbl_staff` where $whr) or die(mysql_error());
```

so, problem is when and where i destroy or unset cookies?

Comment: add expiry time to it

Comment: why do you need the cookie?

Comment: @Oliver you were here 24 seconds before me. So I upvote ur comment.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: beacause i can not use url. the project requirement is url look like clean and safe.

Comment: @dhaval What about $_SESSION?

Comment: same problem with $_SESSION,when and where i unset or destroy it?

Comment: @dhaval Delete the value when you don't need it anymore. You don't have to destroy the session for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a suggestion. You should make one button. And on the click event of that button, clear the cookies. Not a professional solution, though it will definitely work..

Hope it helps.